# XCode "File Not Found" error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode and i am working on a SoundBoard app. In my viewcontroller.m file, I typed in #import " (less than)AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h", only to get the error "File not Found". I did add the AVFoundation.framework file though, so i don't understand why i am getting this error.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement should look like this

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

If you have declared it like this then you might have a problem with how you are adding the AVFoundation Library. In Xcode 4 you need to select the Project in the Project Navigator

Select the Build Phases tab and expand Link Binary With Libraries.
[image]

Click the + button and add AVFoundation.

Hopefully this corrects your issue otherwise its an issue with the Header Search Paths.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your frameworks make sure you do not copy them to your project, just use them in their original locations.  To find out where those frameworks are located right click on a framework and select "show in finder".

This has worked for me.